# Background check is taking a long time (pending misdemeanor on my record)

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, new-job, human-resources, background-check

3 weeks ago, I enthusiastically received an offer from a top aerospace company for a software engineering position. I was referred by a former coworker and immediately received an offer upon interviewing which I signed 3 weeks ago. The recruiter then told me it is contingent upon a background check. I have a pending misdemeanor for a DUI (long story, it is not alcohol related and I am currently working with my attorney to get it expunged). I have no other criminal records or incidents. I did not disclose this, but I answered everything truthfully on the application and background check consent (I was not asked about arrests/DUIs/misdemeanors, only about civil lawsuits/harassment/restraining orders).

I have since had multiple conversations with my future team who is expecting me to start December 2nd, and I just received an official notification from Workday and created my internal account.

Assuming this meant I  passed the check, I probed the recruiter about relocation details and they responded they are still waiting on background check results. It's been almost 3 weeks now.

Should I follow up with the recruiter about this? Should I disclose anything at this point? Any other advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Continue interviewing with other companies just in case. Offers fall through. Hiring gets frozen. Hiring gets delayed. There could be a thousand and one other reasons you might need another job this December.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you have answered all the questions *truthfully*, and did not intentionally hide / withheld information, you don't need to be worried. If you were not asked / expected to reveal any particular information, you don't need to provide it.

Just give it a couple more days. Check back same time next week, if you don't get to hear in the meantime.

Comment: thank you for this response. I did not lie about anything, but I am more than prepared to speak to this incident if they ask. The waiting game is excruciating and I am wondering if I should have just disclosed upfront - do you think that will be self-incriminating at this point?

Comment: @al_coast2 I don;t think you need to do anything else at this point.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I follow up with the recruiter about this?

Yes. But it sounds like you already did ("I probed the recruiter about relocation details and they responded they are still waiting on background check results").

You might wish to ask the recruiter when you should expect the background check to be completed.

> Should I disclose anything at this point?

No. If you wanted to disclose something, that would have been better disclosed before the background check was started. Now, there's no benefit to adding anything into the mix.

> Any other advice on how to proceed?

Try to be patient. These things take time. The other signs you mentioned (conversations with team, and the start of WorkDay account creation) are all good.

You'll likely hear the results soon, one way or the other.

Comment: Do you mean I should ask the recruiter when the check will be complete? Will this look sketchy if/when they do see the pending misdemeanor on my background check?

Comment: I just followed up and immediately heard back that the contingency was lifted from my offer and I am cleared to start next month! I wonder if they even looked at the background check or just plain lifted my contingency. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to wait. Obviously it sounds like the company is readying accounts so you can start on time, but until they get the OK, you aren't officially hired. You might have to ask someone in HR specifically (unless this was an internal recruiter) about your status. If you still haven't heard in a couple of weeks, you'll definitely need to ask whether they are willing to let you to work in a pending status or restart your job search.

Comment: It's an internal recruiter working with a third party agency to do the background check